# Authenticating Google sign-in token through a proxy fails

Tags: android, proxy, google-authentication

I'm using a Google Client Library to verify a token that is returned using Single Tap Sign In (google-api-client-1.32.2). I need to setup a proxy on my device in order to test my Android app locally. This works for a Pixel 2 device running Android 11. But it doesn't work if on a Nexus 6P running Android 8.

It is clear that the proxy is preventing the authentication from succeeding because if I disable the proxy, it works. I tried adding the domain googleapis.com to the list of domains that the proxy will ignore but that didn't help. It is possible that some other domain is also being used for authentication other than googleapis.com.

I use Charles as my proxy, but it doesn't show any domain other than googleapis.com.

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the code, the proxy or anything else. This problem is the result of the same crap that has been happening for years with Android. If the app is already installed on a different device and you clear the app's cache before running the app, you are mistaken to believe that the app's setting are all cleared. Android stores the settings in the cloud in your Google Drive under the device's backup. So when you clear the cache or even reinstall the app, Android retrieves the app's settings from the backup. As a result, the JWT token that get created when you peform a sign-in use API keys that are part of the backup. But if the API keys have changed in the updated app, they will be overwritten by the backup keys.

The solution is to delete the device's backup in Google Drive. I seriously believe that this feature of storing device settings in the Cloud is one of the dumbest things I've encountered. This is not the first time this has happened.